# Can someone in the US on a H4 visa work remotely

Tags: usa, dependent-visa

If I am on a (dependent) H4 visa in the USA, can I

- Work remotely (in the US) for my employer in another country ?
- Create blogs/youtube videos/e-commerce websites which earn me revenue (credited to a bank account in another country) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some debate on the issue, but the consensus is that you can't work while you're in the US independently of where the company you work for is located.

This [article](http://www.bbcamerica.com/mind-the-gap/2012/10/09/so-youre-on-a-spouse-visa-things-to-know/) explains this:

> But the grumble of many job-ready H4 visa holders is that they’re also banned from working remotely for companies back in their home nation. Freelancing, or even continuing to run a business abroad with no trading links to the U.S., would be a violation of the terms of the H4.

And there can be found similar explanation in a lot of places, like [this one](http://www.justanswer.com/immigration-law/50q26-just-spoken-us-attorney-informally-possibility.html):

> The reality is that the laws regulating H-4 status do not not necessarily contemplate a person working remotely but the existing laws explicitly state that a H-4 dependent cannot work unless he or she is the approved beneficiary of an authorized petition and been granted a change of status to a non-immigrant category.

So the answer is: you can't legally work - even if its remote work for a foreign company or freelancing.

There might be however some ways how you can still earn a [little income](http://www.bbcamerica.com/mind-the-gap/2012/10/04/six-legal-ways-to-earn-money-in-the-u-s-without-a-work-visa/).

Answer (score 3):

No, to both. Without EAD H4 person is not allowed to work in the US. The employer identity is not relevant.

You cannot work, you cannot work for a foreign employer, and you cannot for yourself as an employer. You cannot work for free, you cannot do anything that can would done for salary had you not been a H4, and you cannot work "as a partner" for equity or any other kind of compensation (or without compensation).

You can volunteer for an organization who doesn't generally pay salary (like a church/temple etc).